# Que erro é esse "Could not find method agendar(View) in"?

Tags: java, android

Estou chamando um método, quando clico no botão e esse erro aparece, mas não sei o que quer dizer:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method agendar(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'btnAgendar'

Segue meu código

```java
    public class AgendamentoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ProfissionalPojo p;
    private ListView listAgendamentos;
    private Spinner spinnerHorario;

    private String dadoHora;
    private StringCharacterIterator editText;
    private Calendar myCalendar;
    private String diaAgenda;

    private int idusuario;
    private String nome;
    private String sobrenome;
    private String dia;
    private String hora;
    private Button botaoAgenda;

    //private horario adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_agendamento);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        Bundle extra = getIntent().getExtras();

        if(extra != null){
            idusuario = extra.getInt("idusuario");
            nome = extra.getString("nome");
            sobrenome = extra.getString("sobrenome");
        }
        Toast.makeText(this, "id usuario "+idusuario, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        final Calendar myCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        p = (ProfissionalPojo) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("pro");

        agendar(p.getIdprofissional(), idusuario, nome, sobrenome, dia, hora);

        listAgendamentos = ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvAgendamentos));
        botaoAgenda = ((Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAgendar));

        EditText editText = ((EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtDia));

        spinnerHorario = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spHorario);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
                R.array.spHorario, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinnerHorario.setAdapter(adapter);

        spinnerHorario.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                if(i == 0){
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "8:00 - 9:00", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String dadoHora = "8:00 - 9:00";
                }else if (i == 1){
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "9:00 - 10:00", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String dadoHora = "9:00 - 10:00";
                }else if (i == 2){
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "10:00 - 11:00", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String dadoHora = "10:00 - 11:00";
                }else if (i == 3){
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "11:00 - 12:00", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String dadoHora = "11:00 - 12:00";
                }else if (i == 4){
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "12:00 - 13:00", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String dadoHora = "12:00 - 13:00";
                }else if (i == 5){
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "13:00 - 14:00", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String dadoHora = "13:00 - 14:00";
                }else if (i == 6){
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "14:00 - 15:00", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String dadoHora = "14:00 - 15:00";
                }else if (i == 7){
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "15:00 - 16:00", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String dadoHora = "15:00 - 16:00";
                }else if (i == 8){
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "16:00 - 17:00", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String dadoHora = "16:00 - 17:00";
                }else if (i == 9){
                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "17:00 - 18:00", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    String dadoHora = "17:00 - 18:00";
                }

                dadoHora = spinnerHorario.getSelectedItem().toString();
                exibeHora();

            }


            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }

        });

        final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
                myCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
                updateLabel(myCalendar);

            }

        };

        editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new DatePickerDialog(AgendamentoActivity.this, date, myCalendar
                        .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                        myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();

            }
        });

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        String time = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime());
    }

    public void exibeDia(){
        final TextView tvDia = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDia));
        tvDia.setText(diaAgenda);
        dia = tvDia.toString();
    }

    public void exibeHora(){
        final TextView tvHora = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHora));
        tvHora.setText(dadoHora);
        hora = tvHora.toString();
    }


    private void updateLabel(Calendar myCalendar) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        diaAgenda = sdf.format(myCalendar.getTime());
        exibeDia();
    }

    public void agendar(final String idprofissional, int idusuario, String nome, String sobrenome, String dia, String hora) {

        Log.d("TAG", "idpro " + idprofissional + " idusuario " + idusuario + " nome " +nome+ " sobrenome " +sobrenome+ " dia " + dia + " hora " + hora);

    }
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tradução livre do erro:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Não foi possível encontrar o método
>   agendar(View) na Classe ou no Contexto para android:
>   atributo onClick definido na classe de visualização
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton com id 'btnAgendar'

Então na declaração do `xml` do ***btnAgendar***, deve ter algo parecido com:

```
android:onClick="agendar"
```

Para que o método informado seja encontrado no contexto, deverá possuir as seguintes características:

- Deve ser declarado como **public**
- Deve possuir como paramêtro uma **View**
- Não possuir retorno (**void**)

**EXEMPLO**

```
public void agendar(View view){
  agendar(p.getIdprofissional(), idUsuario, nome, sobrenome, dia, hora );
  // aqui voce podera acessar as propriedades da sua classe!
}
```

A [View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)  é a representação do elemento clicado na tela, no seu caso o **btnAgendar**.

Este método deverá estar declarado na Classe informada como `context`([link em inglês](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes.html)) do xml.

```
 <RelativeLayout
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 tools:context=".seu.pacote.SuaActivity"
  ...>
```

Comment: Perfeito, mas e como passo os parâmetros que ele deve "levar junto"? id_profissional, id_cliente, nome...?

Comment: é só você usar normalmente dentro do método!

Comment: exatamente, chamando os atributos com o this  dentro do método.. ou seja, this.id_cliente, this.nome... etc

Comment: Blz, entendi...
Estou seguindo o que vc já disse... No onCreate eu só coloco a chamada desse método, certo? Mas como deve ficar, pois estou tentando fazer isso:
agendar(p.getIdprofissional(), idusuario, nome, sobrenome, dia, hora); e o p.getIdprofissional() fica sublinhado em vermelho... Veja o print no post acima.

Comment: não!!! Se você está usando o **onclik** não precisa adicionar nada no **oncreate**

Comment: Certo, vou testar.

Comment: Fechou! Deu certo kkkkkk

Comment: Então sempre que eu colocar o nome de um método no onClick, no XML, não preciso colocar a chamada dele no onCreate, é só criar o método, certo?

Comment: Exato! colocar no onclick no xml é o mesmo que setar o **setOnClickListener** no **onCreate**!

Answer (score 3):

Você deve ter usado no XML do botão "Agendar" o atributo `onClick` apontando para o método `agendar()`. Para isso funcionar dessa forma, o método tem que ser declarado dessa maneira no Java:

`public void agendar(View v)`

Se quiser usar o método `agendar()` com os parâmetros que você definiu, tem que remover o atributo do XML e setar o listener do botão no código, dessa forma:

```
    botaoAgenda.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            agendar(p.getIdprofissional(), idusuario, nome, sobrenome, dia, hora);
        }
    });
```

E, claro, remover a chamada direta do `agendar()` no seu `onCreate()` senão ele sempre será executado quando a Activity for criada.

Comment: o public void agendar(View v) deve estar dentro ou fora do onCreate?

Comment: Sempre fora, mas como disse, da primeira maneira, você não pode passar parâmetros no método. Eu recomendo fazer da segunda maneira, pois na outra, se você quiser renomear ou excluir o método, vai ter que lembrar sempre de mexer também no XML

Comment: Coloquei a chamada do método, fora do onCreate e agora aparece uma linha vermelha sublinhada e diz "Missing method body, or declare abstract"

Comment: Ta, eu já tenho o método fora do onCreate, mas então tiro os parâmetros desse método?

Comment: Mas a idéia não é chamar esse método com aqueles parâmetros que você estava tentando passar sempre que clicar no botão? Se sim, melhor fazer da segunda maneira que te falei.

Comment: Desculpe, qual é a segunda maneira?

Comment: A que eu postei na resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Para mim funciona da seguinte maneira:

Eu chequei o arquivo  `AndroidManifest.xml`
e a primeira `activity` que inicia com o app (no meu caso, eu queria iniciar com a `.LoginActivity`, mas era `.MainActivity` por default), então fiz as alterações:

```xml
     <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.WhatsappClone">
            <activity android:name=".activity.CadastroActivity"></activity>
            <activity android:name=".activity.MainActivity" />
            <activity android:name=".activity.LoginActivity">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
```

E nas classes `LoginActivity.java` e `MainActivity.java` eu descobri um erro no `onCreate`. Em ambas classes o `setContentView` apontavam para o mesmo layout, por isso acontecia o erro:

> "Could not find method login(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class"