# Como tratar dados inseridos em um fragmento de uma Tabbed Activity no Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity, android-fragment

estou aprendendo a desenvolver usando o Android Studio e estou com uma dúvida de principiante: qual classe eu realizo o tratamento de dados a partir de um clique de botão de um fragmento em uma Tabbed Activity. Para ilustrar de forma simples, criei uma aplicação simples usando Tabbed Activity com um fragmento que contem um edit text e um botão. 
No código da tela, tento chamar a partir do clique do botão uma classe chamada "salvaDados":

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="88dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="132dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="191dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="382dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="salvaDados"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />
```

A ideia (no momento) é simplesmente testar o valor do Edit text, com o seguinte código:

```
     public void salvaDados(){
        Button botao = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        EditText texto = findViewById(R.id.editText);
        if(texto.getText().length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"nao tem nada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"tem dados",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

A dúvida é: em qual classe eu trato isso?
1. tentei criar a classe acima na "atividade mãe" do fragmento e deu erro;
2. tentei criar uma classe separada apenas para tratar dados do fragmento e também deu erro.
3. o exemplo acima é apenas para eu saber onde devo tratar todo o código, visto que posteriormente farei coisas mais complexas como salvar os dados no banco, gerar gráficos em outras telas, etc.

Tem pelo menos 15 horas que estou tentando resolver isso e não consegui achar nenhum tutorial para ajudar. Será que alguém pode me dar uma luz? Desde já, agradeço pela ajuda!

Comment: Envia a classe do seu fragmento onde está o botão e o edittext. Pelo fragmento mesmo dá pra fazer isso, depende de como você tá fazendo. Dentro do fragmento no método onCreateView, você tem como chamar.

Comment: Oi Murillo, tentei chamar do fragmento e ainda não consegui. No momento, a classe onCreateView simplesmente chama o layout com o LayoutInflater inflater e não permite usar o método findViewById. Eu tenho que declarar que estou herdando os dados da tela de layout em outro lugar no onCreate?

Comment: tem como sim, vou responder em base do seu código, ai vc implementa e me da um retorno pra ve se dá certo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui vai um exemplo da classe fragmento que você pode utilizar:

```
public class seuFragmento extends Fragment {


    private View view;
    private Activity activity;

    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        activity = (Activity) context;
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.seu_layout_fragment, container, false);

        salvaDados();

        return view;
    }
    public void salvaDados(){
        Button botao = view.findViewById(R.id.button3);
        EditText texto = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        if(texto.getText().length() == 0){
            Toast.makeText(activity,"nao tem nada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
            Toast.makeText(activity,"tem dados",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Você utiliza a `view` criada em `onCreateView` pra chamar `findViewById`. Utilize o `context` criado em `onAttach` pra usar no `toast`. Na view altera o R.layout.seu_layout_fragment para o seu próprio layout.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta!Entendi o funcionamento da View.Inseri o código,mas não deu certo pois o fragmento de layout não está achando a classe. O erro a seguir aparece: "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method salvaDados(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton with id 'button3'". Pelo que entendi, não tenho que tratar o clique no botão no fragmento do layout, por isso tentei criar um método dentro de "salvaDados" usando setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() mas tb não funcionou. :/

Comment: Pra você utilizar o setOnClickListener... você precisa tirar no xml do botão o onClick:"salvaDados". Talvez a resposta desta pergunta do link possa te ajudar: [IllegalStateException: Could not find method](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/235060/que-erro-%C3%A9-esse-could-not-find-method-agendarview-in)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda Murilo! Funcionou aqui!

Comment: @Wellington, de nada brother, se puder marcar como respondida e/ou como útil eu agradeço, abras